# Parallel resistances and a total resistance less than unity

Tags: resistance

I'm learning basics of electronics and I do not understand something about calculation of parallel resistances.

I see the formula is:

1/Rp = 1/R1 + ... 1/Rn

So following this logic, in this circuit:

[image: Text]

1/Rp = 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 = 3/2

So Rp = 2/3, which is less than 1!

And this surprises me a lot!

Can a resistance be less than 1 in this context?

Can a set of resistors in a parallel circuit increase the voltage (in this case by 50%)?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.My mistake came from a misunderstanding of a fundamental: I thought that the resistance affected the voltage. Now everything is more logical.

Comment: More mind-boggling: *[Negative resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_resistance)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you think 1.0Ω has some particular significance? A fat wire might have resistance measured in micro-ohms.

This statement

> "Can a set of resistors in a parallel circuit increase the voltage (in
> this case by 50%)?"

Does not make a lot of sense to me- the voltage is fixed (that's what the circle symbol at the top means). If there is a constant current, then reducing the resistance will reduce  the voltage proportionally.

If the voltage is fixed (as it is here), then reducing the resistance increases the current proportional to the reciprocal of resistance. If one resistor carries a current ix then three in  parallel carry 3x that current since each has the same voltage across it.

By the way, your diagram should have a dot on the right-hand side as well as the left to indicate that the wires are joined together.

Answer (score 5):

> *Can a resistance be inferior to 1 in this context?*

Here's a resistor that is much smaller than 1 Ω: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://uk.farnell.com/caddock/sr10-0-10-1/resistor-0-1-ohm/dp/1612027). The link takes you to a 0.1 Ω resistor but you can have a lot smaller than this.

1 Ω means that 1 amp flows when 1 volt is applied to its terminals; it's not some limit value set in nature --> that value is zero Ω.

> *Can a set of resistors in a parallel circuit increase the voltage (in
> this case by 50%)?*

No amount of parallel resistance applied to a theoretical voltage source will alter the voltage from that source. For more practical real-life situations, unless there is some clever circuit inside the voltage supply, adding resistance to its terminals is only ever going to reduce the voltage.

Answer (score 5):

> Can a resistance be inferior to 1 in this context?

Yes.  All of the standard units in the [International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) (of which Ohms is one) are ultimately arbitrary, and historically derived from things like what length is convenient to use as a unit to measure cloth, dividing the length of a day by exactly 86400 to get a "smallest" measure of time, etc.

For nearly all practical purposes, you can assume that all units you might use in electrical engineering are continuous.  The only exceptions to this that I can think of are rare -- but can loom large if they happen to bite you.  At your level, ignore them -- just be ready to accept them if you start working in an area where quantum physics starts to matter.

These exceptions are the electron charge (\$1.602176634 \cdot 10^{−19}\$ of a Coulomb) and the photon: the electron charge matters because the indivisibility of the Coulomb causes shot noise; the photon matters for a variety of reasons, but at least where it's impacted me it's also been in shot-noise effects, or questions of the ultimate lower limit of the sensitivity of an optical device.

Comment: “the indivisibility of the Coulomb causes shot noise” - I didn’t come here expecting to learn this, but I did. Thank you!